# How to convert table() command to receive the frequency from a third column?

Tags: r

Having a dataframe like this one:

```
df1 <- data.frame(stock = c("Google, Yahoo", "Google", "Yahoo, Google", "Amazon, Google", "Google, Amazon"), investor = c("Nathalie","George","Nathalie, George", "Melanie, George","Melanie"))
```

It is possible using this the frequency of every stock frequency

```
table(sapply(strsplit(as.character(df1$stock), ", "), function(x) toString(sort(x))))
```

How is it possible to add a filter to have the frequency of every stock but based on a third column which shows the selection preference of investors.
Here is the example of expected output:

```
data.frame(investor = c("Nathalie", "George", "George", "George", "Melanie", "Malanie"), stock = c("Google, Yahoo", "Google", "Google, Yahoo", "Amazon, Google", "Amazon, Google", "Amazon"), frq = c(2,1,1,1,1,1))
```

> ```
>  investor          stock frq
> 1 Nathalie  Google, Yahoo   2
> 2   George         Google   1
> 3   George  Google, Yahoo   1
> 4   George Amazon, Google   1
> 5  Melanie Amazon, Google   1
> 6  Malanie         Amazon   1
> ```

Add one more column:

```
df1 <- data.frame(stock = c("Google, Yahoo", "Google", "Yahoo, Google", "Amazon, Google", "Google, Amazon"), investor = c("Nathalie","George","Nathalie, George", "Melanie, George","Melanie"), year = c("2017", "2018", "2017", "2018", "2017"))
```

Comment: Are you splitting the names of 'investor'

Comment: @akrun yes I want to split the names of investor for this case

Comment: @akrun or possible something like melt

Comment: I am not getting the exact output as you showed `df1$stock <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df1$stock), ", "), function(x) toString(sort(x)))
; df1 %>% mutate_all(as.character) %>% separate_rows(investor) %>% add_count(stock, investor)`

Comment: @akrun thank you. I updated the data. Could it more easy with one more melt variable "year" to take the same expected results but melting them through the year?

Comment: Not clear about the 'year' part.  Can you update the input example

Comment: @akrun I updated it at the end of question the input df

Comment: Do you need `library(dplyr);df1 %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% separate_rows(investor) %>% add_count(stock, investor, year)` after the `df1$stock <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df1$stock), ", "), function(x) toString(sort(x)))`

Comment: @akrun thank you. Do you receive an error like this Error: unexpected symbol in "df1 %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% separate_rows(investor) %>% add_count(stock, investor, year) after" ?

Comment: I think you also copied the `after` which is not the code

Comment: @akrun thank you. You are right again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After we sort the values as in the previous step, instead of doing the `table` directly, update the column by assigning, then we can use `tidyverse` methods to split the row of 'investor' and create a count column with `add_count`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1$stock <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df1$stock), ", "),
                function(x) toString(sort(x)))
df1 %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
  separate_rows(investor) %>% 
  add_count(stock, investor, year)
```